# How do you use Qutecom to connect to other services?

Tags: jabber, libpurple

I read on Wikipedia that it uses libpurple, but I can't figure out how to connect to other services (like jabber for example). Am I missing something or is the feature just not there anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qutecom requires you to be signed into your SIP account before you can connnect to other services (The abiltity to use it to chat with other services is a secondary feature).

Answer (score 1):

Clients of libpurple don't have to use all the protocols, or have them as options. Looking at the QuteCom wiki and various documents I could find, it looks like they're using libpurple for specific backend/frontend handling and their client doesn't support other protocols.

Have you tried connecting to QuteCom's backend using Empathy?

Comment: From a quick search for ICQ/Jabber in the bug tracker, it looks like it should work or at least have worked at some time. Unfortunately I got no feedback at #qutecom.

Comment: all the links I could find recently indicated that qutecom should work with other protocols as did wengo. I'll try IRC and see if I get anything, if not I'll just have to accept this as the answer :P